Oracle 21 autonomous database, OCI free tier, no privileges to disable FLASHBACK on a table
Issue:
How to disable flashback on a table, in Oracle free tier autonomous database 21c? Seems to be a lack of privilege problem, there is no ability to raise a support ticket in the OCI free tier. Note, no access to SYSDBA account.
Cannot disable Flashback on a table, but can enable flashback. Using the ADMIN database user account. When executing the query:
-- this will work
ALTER TABLE MAIN.TB_DEV_EXAMPLE106_NOTE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE;

-- this fails with privilege error
ALTER TABLE MAIN.TB_DEV_EXAMPLE106_NOTE NO FLASHBACK ARCHIVE;


The following error is returned when disabling Flashback for the table
ORA-55620: No privilege to use Flashback Archive

Environment:

OCI, free tier
Autonomous database 21c

Lack of privileges on ADMIN

seems on the free tier, maybe limited privileges for ADMIN user
cannot grant `FLASHBACK ARCHIVE' to ADMIN, returns an error:

GRANT FLASHBACK ARCHIVE ON FLASHBACK_ARCHIVE TO ADMIN

-- returns this error
-- ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Current privileges as ADMIN user:
Logged in as ADMIN and run the query
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'ADMIN' AND PRIVILEGE LIKE '%FLASH%';

Returns just 1 row: FLASHBACK ANY TABLE


See the alter table documentation, specifically the "Additional Prerequisites for Flashback Data Archive Operations" section: "To ... disable historical tracking for the table, you must have the FLASHBACK ARCHIVE ADMINSTER system privilege or you must be logged in as SYSDBA". So it sounds like ADMIN doesn't have that privilege; and you can't grant privileges to yourself.

@AlexPoole, thanks, you are correct, no access to SYSDBA, thus cannot grant required privileges to ADMIN user.

Also see The ADMIN User and the SYS User in the documentation. Looks like you probably just can't do this, unless there's a wrapper procedure for it.

Firstly, since this an Autonomous Database Serverless (ADB-S) instance, please refer to the ADB-S doc for flashback time travel:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/serverless/adbsb/flashback-time-travel-autononomous.html#GUID-A98E1F8B-FAE4-4FFF-955D-3A0E5F8EBC4A
ADMIN user by default has FLASHBACK ARCHIVE privilege and ADMIN can grant it to other DB users as well.
I just tried your example in my environment and I was able to enable and disable flashback archive on a given table using the ADMIN user. Are you sure both your enable and disable statements are executed with ADMIN user (or a user with FLASHBACK ARCHIVE privilege)?
Edit: My first tests were on 19c paid and Always Free images where this works as expected. However, I just gave it a try in a 21c Always Free instance as well and verified the behavior you are observing. I will file a bug for this with our development team and update the doc accordingly if it's a 21c limitation. That being said, 21c will be going away soon and will be replaced with 23c. Always Free will have 19c and 23c options. As an immediate workaround, I would recommend 19c Always Free instance.

@ctuzia, thanks for the amazing reply. Logged in as ADMIN on OCI SQL console. The ADMIN has privilege to FLASHBACK ANY TABLE but not the FLASHBACK ARCHIVE. Please see the screen shot on the updated question. Can the correct privilege be added? We eagerly await 23c, Oracle DBs are the best, but this is a real problem for my client!

@Rax I just confirmed with our development team that it's indeed an issue with 21c. In other words, 21c is missing some functionality such as this privilege. This feature is not supported in 21c and we'll update our doc accordingly ASAP. Now, coming back to how we can unblock you and provide a workaround. Given 21c is going away very soon and 23 will be available even sooner, would it be acceptable for you to either use 19c Always Free or wait for 23 Always Free? If you would like to still disable FDA for this table, our OPS team should be able to help you regarding that as well. DM me please.

Brilliant thanks for the confirmation. We can await 23 rollout. Though please can I take up the offer of support and disable FDA for a few tables, as they cannot be deleted either! Not sure how to DM you on StackOverflow. I managed to send you an connect invite on LinkedIn. My name is Rakesh Patel, thanks so much.
